# when I use keras.layers.MaxPool1d function, I got an error, How do I solve it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf

INPUT_SIZE = (1,28,28)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=INPUT_SIZE)
dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)(inputs)
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
    filters=10,
    kernel_size=3,
    padding='same',
    activation=tf.nn.relu)(dropout)
max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=3,padding='same')(inputs)
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(max_pool)
```

I get

```
ValueError  Traceback (most recent call last)
    
    <ipython-input-5-b1507741c881> in <module>()
         10     padding='same',
         11     activation=tf.nn.relu)(dropout)
    ---> 12 max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=3,padding='same')(inputs)
         13 flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(max_pool)
    
    5 frames
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
        221                          'expected ndim=' + str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
        222                          str(ndim) + '. Full shape received: ' +
    --> 223                          str(tuple(shape)))
        224     if spec.max_ndim is not None:
        225       ndim = x.shape.rank
    
  ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling1d_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 1, 28, 28)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: your data is 4d... use Conv2d and MaxPool2D

Comment: Yeap, you seem to be working with the MNIST dataset, made of 2D images. As Marco suggested, you should use 2D versions of the algorithms.

Comment: The main issue is you're passing 2d data to 1d layer (maxpool1d). Changing it to 2d, simply solve the error. But you should conv2d with some meaningful parameter to avoid negative diemtion error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some different cases of `MaxPooling - 1D, 2D, 3D`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

INPUT_SIZE = (1,28,28) # 2D data channel x height x width 

x  = tf.keras.Input(shape=INPUT_SIZE)
print(x.shape) # (None, 1, 28, 28)

# MaxPool2D
x_max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=3,padding='same')(x) # x:2D, MaxPool2D
```

`MaxPool1D`

```
y = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x) # 2D to 1D
y = tf.reshape(y, [1, -1, 1])
print(y.shape) # (1, None, 1)

# MaxPool1D
y_max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=3)(y)
```

`MaxPool3D`

```
z = tf.expand_dims(inputs, axis=-1) # 2D to 3D
print(z.shape) # (None, 1, 28, 28, 1)

# MaxPool3D
z_max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=3, padding='same')(z)
```

Comment: Isnt INPUT_SIZE (batch_size x height x width x channel) ?

Comment: OP had a channel first input format. You're referring channel last format.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just curiosity, how tensorflow deal with different input formats?